# Reading a line using fscanf()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to read a line from a file using fscanf():

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c, *string[4];
    int i = 0,j[4];
    fp = fopen("boil.txt", "r");
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if(fp == NULL)
    { printf("File read error\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(c != '\n')
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %d ", string[i] , &j[i]);
        i++;
        c = fgetc(fp);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s      %d\n", string[i], j[i]);
    }
}
```

boil.txt is as follow:

```
boil 4 boilmilk 3 boilwater 5 heat 10
```

Why this program is giving Segmentation Fault?

Comment: You need to allocate memory, your `string[i]` pointers point to random locations.

Comment: Be careful here as well, fgetc and fscanf both move the file pointer ahead, you may not be getting the characters you want.

Comment: 1) No error checking 2) `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reasons. 3) No space allocated. 4) etc. 5) See [ask].

Comment: @crlanglois: Should I use two file pointers instead of one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't reserve space for such strings:

```
char *string[4];
```

is an array of pointers to string, but you need room to store those strings, something like:

```
char temp[256];

fscanf(fp, "%s %d ", temp , &j[i]);
string[i] = strdup(temp);
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by iRove, `strdup` is not part of the standard (but available on many implementations), if you can't use `strdup`, an alternative is:

```
string[i] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
if (string[i] == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(string[i], temp);
```

Don't forget to call free at the end (when the strings are no longer needed)

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) free(string[i]);
```

Comment: You have to keep in mind that `strdup()` is not actually a part of the ISO C standard.

Comment: Thank you for taking that into account.  :-)

Comment: And thak you too ;)

Comment: @AlterMann: Thank you.I allocated memory space using malloc but still getting Segmentation Fault.Could you please figure out why I am getting now segmentation fault.Also, I've no upper bound on the length of strings.So how should I implement it instead of using _char temp[256]_?

Comment: Reviewing your code there are several problems 1) `c = fgetc(fp);`, after `fopen`:  if program fails to open the file in read mode this can cause a segmentation fault, remove this line. 2) `while(c != '\n')`: this can be a problem if your file doesn't contain a new line, the correct way is `while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)` (you need to declare c as `int` instead of `char`) 3) Don't mix `fscanf` and `fgetc`, I suggest you to take a look to `fgets` in conjunction with `strtok` for this task (using a white space as delimiter). Give it a try and turn back if you are in troubles.